# Dynamically adding Textbox in asp.net using C#

Tags: asp.net, textbox, placeholder

I have written a code in which a textbox is dynamically added to a gridview cell. There is some default texts in the textbox. I want that when users will click on the textbox the default text will disappear and the user can then write anything on it only in number, i.e. the user will not be able to use letters or special characters.

Kindly let me know how to achieve this.
Code example

```
    Gridview gv=new Gridview();
    gv.DataSource=dt;
    gv.DataBind();

    Textbox t1 = new Textbox();
    t1.Text="Outages if any(in mins)";
    gv.Rows[0].Cells[0].Controls.Add(t1);
```

Need help after this, something like when user puts his cursor in the textbox , the default text will disappear , and if the user removes the cursor without writing anything , the default text will reappear. Also the default text should be a bit blurred

Thanks.

Comment: The kind of behavior you're looking for is really not intended to be handled server-side, at least not ideally. You'll need to write some javascript for the client browser to handle some of your UI requirements.

Comment: For more information to further your research, look into placeholders. They accomplish exactly what you are attempting to do and there is tons of information out there about them.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this

```
Textbox t1 = new Textbox();
t1.Attributes.Add("onclick", "if(this.value == 'default text') this.value = '';"
t1.Attributes.Add("onblur", "if(this.value == '') this.value = 'default text';" />
```

You could also use `onfocus` in case users use `tab` key

With this, using `this.value`, approach you don't need to know the client ID of the control.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a post describing exactly what you are looking to do:

[HowTo: including default text in a Textbox while enforcing server-side validation](http://weblogs.asp.net/jasonsalas/archive/2004/09/30/235932.aspx)

The pertinent points are:

1. Adding javascript attribute to onfocus & and onblur:

   ```
   txtName.Attributes.Add("onfocus","clearText()"); 
   txtName.Attributes.Add("onblur","resetText()");
   ```
2. Adding the javascript to clear and repopulate the textbox:

   ```
       function clearText() { 
           document.form1.txtName.value = "" 
       } 

       function resetText() { 
           if(document.form1.txtName.value == "") 
               document.form1.txtName.value = "(enter something here)"
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this.  The easiest way is to use the ajaxControlToolkit.  You can create controls dynamically.  For example:

```
    Dim mt As new TextBox 
    Dim newTest As New AjaxControlToolkit.TextBoxWatermarkExtender

    With mt
        .ID = "textBox1"
        .TextMode = TextBoxMode.SingleLine
    End With

    With newTest
        .ID = "TextBoxWatermarkExtender1"
        .TargetControlID = mt.ClientID
        .WatermarkText = "test"

    End With
```

Then just add both controls to the gridview as you are doing with the textbox.  If you are not using Ajax, you can add javascript to the control through codebehind but this is more difficult.  Let me know if that is what you want to do and Ill add some code to show you how.

This should create a textbox control with an associated ajax TextBoxWaterMarkExtender.